# Hasse-Weil Zeta Functions & Fermats Last Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions

Maybe this is a bit naive, but consider an equation of the form in Fermats Last Theorem $f_n(x,y,z) = x^n +y^n - z^n$.

Would it be possible to reprove Fermats Last Theorem by considering the Hasse-Weil zeta function $L(X, s)$ of the projective variety $X$ cut out by $f_n$ and analyzing special values on the left side of the right half plane for which $L(f_n,s)$ is defined?

Are there any conjectures/beliefs out there of such a proof?

Comment: This is stated, of course, in the whole-hearted belief that such a function would have Analytic/Meromorphic Continuation to all of the complex numbers.

Answer (score 7):

<del>The only method we know of to prove analytic / meromorphic continuation of zeta-functions of alg. varieties over number fields is to go via some kind of modularity, or potential modularity, statement. So even making sense of the statement of your program **already requires** the key piece of technology developed to prove FLT (and modularity of these high-degree Fermat curves is likely to be *vastly* harder than elliptic curves).</del>

<del>That is, your "whole-hearted belief" makes this proposed program circular.</del>

EDIT: Dan Loughran's comment alerted me to the fact that this is misleading. Fermat curves have lots of automorphisms, and there are enough of these to force the L-function to factor as a product of L-functions of Groessencharacters of cyclotomic fields, for which analytic continuation + functional equation of the L-function are known; see [Aoki (1991)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374786). This is, of course, an automorphy statement of a kind, but one that's far easier than automorphy of general higher-genus curves would be.

There are several remaining serious obstacles. For instance, once you go beyond genus 1, the link between the special values of the L-function of a curve and the existence or otherwise of rational points on the curve is very indirect. Rather than points on $X$, the $L$-series gives you information about points on $Jac(X)$. Sometimes, with lots of extra work, you can translate this into information about points on $X$ itself (the Chabauty--Coleman method), but there are lots of cases where this does not apply.

Comment: I would have thought that the Hasse-Weil zeta function of Fermat curves should be much easier to understand than general curves due to the presence of automorphisms. I means the curve $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ is an elliptic curve with complex multiplication. I imagine modularity in this case is much easier than the general case due to the description of the $L$-function in terms of Hecke characters. Though I agree that the question is very misguided.

Comment: @DanielLoughran You're right. Oops.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is something similar to the analytic class number formula, where you can read off an invariant ( the numbers of real and complex embeddings) which, by Dirichlets unit theorem, tells you if the Norm of that field equals 1, as a polynomial, has infinitely many solutions or not. Maybe this just is not the case. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @EIns Nell: The Hasse-Weil zeta function of a variety does not tell you whether there is a rational point. The zeta function of any plane conic over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)$, but of course some conics have rational points while others do not.

Comment: There is an invariant -- the genus -- which will tell you that the Fermat curve *for a given $n$* has finitely rational points (because of Faltings' proof of the Mordell conjecture). But for FLT we need to show that there are no non-trivial solutions at all, for any value of $n > 2$, which is a very different problem indeed.